# move <td class="45-record"> to the last of the previous <tr>

Tags: jquery, html

I have this table layout

[image]

I'm trying to move the qty field on the row with **-fullfit** (e.g. 45-fullfit) up above the previous row, to be positioned to the last column..

here's the html code

[image]

here's my partial code

```
jQuery("tr").each(function(index, el) {
  var tdfull = jQuery("[class$='-fullfit']"); //successful on finding <td>'s with "-fullfit" suffixes
  jQuery(this).prev("tr").append(tdfull); //adds all the <td>'s on the last row
})
```

this should be the result

[image]

Comment: see my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following loop:

```
$('[class$="fullfit"]').each(function(){
 var el = $(this).closest('tr').prev();//go to the parent tr get the previous tr
 el.append($(this));//append the current element to the tr
});
```

demo:

```js
$('[class$="fullfit"]').each(function() {
   var el = $(this).closest('tr').prev();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
   el.append($(this));
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>5'5''-5'2'</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td class="45">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5'5''-5'2'</td>
    <td>45 fullfit</td>
    <td class="45-fullfit">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5'5''-5'2'</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td class="45">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5'5''-5'2'</td>
    <td>45 fullfit</td>
    <td class="45-fullfit">
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```